# Products are not showing on category and search result

Tags: product

**Products are not showing in category and search result.**

Products detail -

Status - Enable

Visibility - Catalog, Search

Assigned to right Website, Store, Categories

It's group product. Inventory set Manage Stock 'Yes' , Stock Availability 'In Stock'

Simple product which associated in have stocks and in stock (I also setup show out of stock products)

Reindex all index, Flush all caches

Category is active

I create a test sample product on admin product grid and assigned to the same category, the test sample product is showing correctly on the category

**What should I check?**

UPDATE - I think I reindex all few more but still products can not be search or not show in front-end , the products are showing correctly on admin

Not a new store, the previous products are showing well

Comment: Please check the system->configuration->catalog check system setting here...

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the followings as well.

- Your category is under the relevant `root category`.
- Under the `Display Settings` tab of category, the Display Mode should set to "`Products Only`" or "`Static blocks and products"`. (If this is set to "Static block only`", the products will not display for the category.)
- Clear all the cache (including browser cache)
- Ensure all the products (including associate products) `have qty > 0`
- Make sure product inventory is set to `'Is in stock' => true`
- Try this with Magento default theme, If the products are shown in the default theme, then the issue is with your custom theme.